# CJK ctexart LuaLaTeX. Either characters shows "F" or Author has "UU" (See picture)

Tags: luatex, fontspec, cjk, ctex, luatexja

MWE for the first example:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{float} % Force Floats of picture
\usepackage{wrapfig} %wrap text
\usepackage{soul} % for strike through \st{}
\usepackage[overlap,CJK]{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.55}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.45ex}
% \usepackage{xeCJK}
% \setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{CJKutf8}
% \usepackage{CJK}
% \usepackage{libertine} 

% \usepackage{antpolt}
% \usepackage{xunicode} % to change the fonts
% % \setmainfont[ItalicFont=ipaexm.ttf]{Linux Libertine O}

% \newcommand{\cvspace}{\vskip 1.2em}\directlua{
% \directlua {
%   luaotfload.add_multiscript("cjk",
%       {
%         Kana = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=kana;",
%         Hira = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=hira;",
%       }
%     )
%   }
% }
% \setCJKmonofont[RawFeature={multiscript=cjk}]{Linux Libertine O}
% \setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
% \usepackage{CJK}
% \usepackage{luatexja}
% \usepackage{xeCJK}[2011/05/20 v2.4.1]
% \setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}
% \setCJKfamilyfont{jarm}{ipaexm.ttf}
% \newfontfamily\Japanese[]{ipaexm.ttf} % NotoSerifCJKjp

% \newfontfamily{\japaneseFamily}{NotoSerifCJKjp-Regular}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
% \usepackage{babel}
% \babelprovide{japanese}
% \babelfont[japanese]{rm}{NotoSerifCJKjp-Regular}

% \setCJKmainfont{NotoSerifCJKjp-Regular}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
% \setCJKmainfont{YuMincho}

% \setCJKfamilyfont{song}{ipaexm.ttf}
% \newcommand*{\Japanese}{\CJKfamily{song}}

\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-2,-3}}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % Strike Chinese

\usepackage{emoji}
\title{胡言乱语}
\author{刘志远}
\date{June 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

% \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{ipxm}
% 現実
% \end{CJK*}

\noindent\ruby{大人}{おとな}になるのは\ruby{多分}{たぶん}\\
Becoming an adult probably means,\\
\ruby{友達}{ともだち}と\ruby{話}{はな}したり\ruby{会}{あ}ったりする\\
that meeting up and talking with friends\\
ことは\ruby{少}{すく}なくなること\\
becomes more infrequent.\\
それが\ruby{現実}{げんじつ}なんです\\
That is reality.\\
でも、もしも\ruby{話}{はな}せない\ruby{日}{ひ}が\ruby{来}{く}るなら\\
But, if the day comes when we stop talking,\\
\ruby{君}{きみ}に\ruby{伝}{つて}えたいんが\\
I wanted to tell you,\\
\ruby{会}{あ}えてあかったって\\
``I'm glad to have met you."\\
いっぱい\ruby{思}{おも}い\ruby{出}{で}を\ruby{作}{つく}ったね\\
``We made a lot of memories, didn't we?"\\
そして、その想い出が\ruby{私}{わたし}の\ruby{中}{なか}に\ruby{永遠}{えいえん}に\ruby{生}{い}き\ruby{続}{つづ}ける\\
``also, those memories would always stay with me."\\
ありがとう\\
Thank you.
% Source instagram
\end{document}
```

Commented since those did not help me.

[image: Some Characters are not displaying]

Or I can fix it with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[UTF8,nofonts]{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Serif CJK JP}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Serif CJK JP}
\usepackage[margin=1.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{soul} % for strike through \st{}
\usepackage[overlap,CJK]{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.55}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.45ex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % Strike Chinese
\usepackage{emoji}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ℕ}{\mathbb{N}}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{志远的胡言乱语}
\author{刘志远}
\date{June 2023}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

気に入ったの一つですね。

\texttt{気に入ったの一つですね。}

\textbf{気に入ったの一つですね。}

\textsc{気に入ったの一つですね。}

\end{document}
```

But now it has the UU displaying before the author name:

[image: UU :(]

So the reason that I am using LuaLaTeX is because I want to insert emojis.

How do I fix both: "UU" in author? And display all Chinese and Japanese characters? (possibly Japanese in a small environment and Chinese for the main environment. Both should have Noto Serif CJK font (or similar).)

I have looked up so many questions and answers and got no good results.

Comment: Please add a full MWE, not just the preamble. (And not just as a screenshot) Otherwise it's very hard to test.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to, one moment

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `disablejfam` option to `luatexja`, which can be done as a global option.

```
\documentclass[UTF8,fontset=none,disablejfam]{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=1.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{luatexja}

\usepackage{soul} % for strike through \st{}
\usepackage[overlap,CJK]{ruby}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % Strike Chinese
\usepackage{emoji}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\usepackage[
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor = blue,
  urlcolor  = blue,
  citecolor = blue,
  anchorcolor = blue,
]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setCJKmainfont{SongtiSC}
\setCJKsansfont{SongtiSC}
\setCJKmonofont{SongtiSC}

\renewcommand{\rubysize}{0.55}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.45ex}

\newunicodechar{ℕ}{\mathbb{N}}

\title{志远的胡言乱语}
\author{刘志远}
\date{June 2023}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

気に入ったの一つですね。

\texttt{気に入ったの一つですね。}

\textbf{気に入ったの一つですね。}

\textsc{気に入ったの一つですね。}

\end{document}
```

Note. I changed the font to one that I have and has all the required glyphs (not sure what small caps is intended to do).

I also noticed that the font size in the title changes when `ruby` is loaded.

I reorganized the preamble to have package loading first and settings later.

The `nofonts` option is deprecated and should be `fontset=none`.

[image]